# In C, I wrote a program to call an exe using system(). The exe asks for user input. How can I make my program provide the input?

Tags: c, system, parent-child

I've seen posts that are like this, but I couldn't find the exact answer to my question.
I wrote a program in C that calls another exe I wrote by saying `system("./program_name");`. The program that is called asks for user input, and based on what is input, displays one of three strings to the screen.

Once `system("./program_name");` runs the program, is there some way I can also make my program provide the input? I want this program to be able to run the other one multiple times, by providing different inputs each time. Then, I would like the program to display which inputs caused string 2 to be output.

In other words, program 1 asks for input and displays String A, B, or C.
Program 2 runs program 1 several times with different inputs, and displays which inputs resulted in String B.

I'm stuck on being able to provide the input from my program.

Thanks in advance for your help!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `system`, you probably want to use `popen` (or, in Microsoft-land, `_popen`). This lets you open the child program *and* gives you a `FILE *` through which you can read the child's standard output, or write to the child' standard input (depending on whether you specify "r" or "w" as the open mode). Although non-standard, some reasonably recent versions allow both reading and writing (which it sounds like you'd really prefer).

If you can't do the latter, since you seem to be doing this on Windows, you can/could use `CreateProcess` to create the child with both input and output redirected. It's much more versatile, but also a *lot* more work.

Comment: Read-write can be problematic. If output of the child process is buffered, it can deadlock.

Comment: @Barmar: Unfortunately quite true. The standard library *should* recognize that when they're connected to pipes like this they aren't interactive, and therefore shouldn't buffer -- but that doesn't quite agree with actual experience.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the standard library to tell that the two pipes are both connected to the same calling process.

Comment: @Barmar: It doesn't really need to -- it only buffer when they're interactive. If they're connected to different programs (e.g., via pipes) it's still fine to stop buffering.

Comment: It's the other way around: stdout is buffered when it's connected to a pipe or file, not buffered when it's connected to a terminal. Popen always uses a pipe, there's no way for the child to know that `rw` opens two pipes to the same program.

Comment: I can deal with only using write, so this is perfect, thank you so much! I had no idea popen existed, and it worked exactly how I wanted it to. I'm going to modify my program a bit so that the read option isn't needed. I'll also look into popen some more, and try to avoid read-write. Thanks again!!